# "Du masculin" au lieu de "un masculin"

Tags: articles

Dans un livre ([Larousse Thématique : Dictionnaire des difficultés de la langue française](https://fr.shopping.rakuten.com/mfp/8217/dictionnaire-des-difficultes-de-la-langue-francaise-adolphe-v-thomas?pid=1360987)) le lemme pour ouvrage dit :

> Ouvrage est **du masculin** : Un ouvrage bien fait. Travailler à un ouvrage (Acad.). Il est néanmoins employé au féminin dans certaines expressions familières qui sont issues du langage populaire (...)

Du est-il ici l'article partitif ? Je ne comprends pas son emploi dans ce contexte. Pourquoi pas un masculin ?

Comment: « C'est un masculin » est aussi possible . Dans un cas on fait l’ellipse du mot mot (dénombrable) et de l'autre du mot genre (indénombrable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux se disent par ellipse comme déjà répondu ou commenté mais l'absence d'article (***ouvrage est masculin***) est bien plus courante.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

C'est un raccourci pour "du *genre* masculin", et une formulation inattendue ici, car elle me semble plutôt datée. Je m'y attendrais plus d'un ouvrage du 19e ou 18e siècle